# How to find the Taylor expansion of this trig function?

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

I have been trying to find the taylor expansion of:

$y=\arccos(sech(x))$

I have found the taylor series of:

$\arccos(x)=\frac{\pi}{2}-x+...$

$sech(x)= 1- \frac{x^{2}}{2}+...$

but then $\arccos(sech(x))=\frac{\pi}{2}-1+\frac{x^{2}}{2}+...$

I have plotted this on the graphing calculator and it does not seem to approximate the curve at all. I am more expecting something like $y=x$ for this equation. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gudermannian_function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compose the series from inside
$$\text{sech}(x)=1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{5 x^4}{24}-\frac{61 x^6}{720}+O\left(x^8\right)$$
So,
$$\cos ^{-1}(\text{sech}(x))=x-\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^5}{24}+\frac{299 x^7}{13440}+O\left(x^8\right)$$ which is quite good up to $x=1$; but this is for $x>0$ (change the signs if $x<0$.

To give you an idea, the norm
$$\Phi=\int_0^1 \big[\text{exact - approximate}\big]^2\,dx=6.72\times 10^{-5}$$